# How could I bind the vim navigational keys to the same as in emacs?

Tags: vim

I'd like to bind these:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> one character forward
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> one character backward
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> go to the line below the current one ( not in insert mode )
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> go to the line above the current one ( not in insert mode )

Which functions should I bind? How could I find them?

Comment: are you sure to migrate from `vim` to `emacs`? +1 to effort.

Comment: I'm confused, do you want to do it in Vim or Emacs?

Comment: I want to try vim for a while :)

Comment: @Tempus: You want to try out vim but make it behave like Emacs ?  Whatever turns you on.

Comment: I got used to it's navigational settings. They became second nature :)

Answer (score 4):

On vim.org you can find a script called [Vimacs](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=300) : Vim-Improved eMACS: Emacs emulation for Vim

The short description says:

> Vimacs (Vim-Improved eMACS) brings Emacs's extensive key bindings and modeless editing features to the Vim world, while completely retaining Vim's powerful moded editing style.

So I guess this is all you need.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want those four mappings and not the full Vimacs, you can do this:

```
nmap <c-f> l
nmap <c-b> h
nmap <c-n> j
nmap <c-p> k
```

To get ctrl-f and ctrl-b to work in insert mode add these:

```
imap <c-f> <right>
imap <c-b> <left>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the map command.

```
:h :map
```

You might want to consider learning the vim mappings. (h/l and j/k are shorter than ctrl-f/ctrl-b and ctrl-n/ctrl-p).
Also, check out..

```
:h index
```

.. for a list of the mappings.